# Tflite gives different accuracy/behaviour in python interpreter and iOS

Tags: python, ios, swift, numpy, tensorflow

I have custom trained an object detection model using **Training and serving a realtime mobile object detector** article [link](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193). After training and converting the model to tflite, I used the Python interpreter to test the model and then integrated it with iOS by following **github tflite iOS exmaple** [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/ios). The model works fine on python interpreter but shows entirely different behavior in iOS by detecting wrong objects and low confidence scores.

I have tried a couple of models which includes:

1. ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_coco
2. ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_coco

The default tflite model **detect.tflite** [provided in iOS github exmaple](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/ios) works in the iOS and also in the python interpreter but the custom model does not.

The python interpreter code for reference

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
# change the following line to feed into your own data.
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue (in android). Have you solved it?

Comment: Hey. Have you had any success with this?

Comment: any success with this?